# How does OpenEdge Progress-4GL work with ActiveX tabstrip component?

Tags: user-interface, activex, openedge, progress-4gl, tabpage

I would like to work with a tabstrip in my OpenEdge Progress-4GL environment, but I can't make it work.

"*No problem: there's an example on the Progress website.*", you might say, and indeed on [this URL](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/How-to-access-folder-tabs-at-design-time-of-MS-TabStrip-OCX) there's an example of a tabstrip (you might need to download the mentioned "TabStrip_sample.zip"), where a Listview is placed on one of the tabs and a Treeview on the other tab. (Don't be afraid: the zipfile only contains source code, bitmaps and an automatically created `*.wrx` file, which won't harm your computer)

Now the question: how on Earth did they do it?

Into the file "dbtest.w" let's have a look at both tabs at design time (after having resized the Listview):
[image]

It is clear that all components are put on the TabStrip component, so the linking between the tabs and the components should be done at runtime (just as mentioned in the URL), but here's the catch:

There seems not to be any event handler `ON ... CFTabStrip` or anything in the code.
The keys ("Db_tbl" and "Db_sch") NOR the indexes (1 and 2) of the individual tab pages, mentioned in `CFTabStrip`'s property editor, are nowhere to be seen in the code.

Can anyone explain me how they did it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You are using 11.6 and seem to be creating a new updated front-end. If so, I would skip the AppBuilder and ActiveX controls and just use .Net controls. If you want to use the Visual Designer (which really helps to get started for prototyping) you will need to be using Progress Developer Studio for OpenEdge. Additionally, UI widgets should never interact with the database, but use at least one extra layer -> see using DataSets.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't start using a new IDE just now.

Comment: You can create the .Net widgets /without/ a new IDE. It's just easier to prototype widget creation using the Visual Designer to see which classes are used and which properties are set. To have a first look at the Visual Designer you can download the OpenEdge Evaluation Kit - https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P25497

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "magic" is in `PROCEDURE CFTabStrip.TabStrip.MouseDown`, which checks if the horizontal location (x) would have meant the first tab or the right tab and then hides / shows one or the other.

Pretty clunky, but if you look at the header, this example was created nearly twenty years ago to work with Progress 8.

Comment: Clunky indeed, but the numbers, used for the x-coordinates (smaller than 105 and larger than 108) are based on the captions of the tab pages. I can accept 3 as a hardcoded width of the separator between the tabpages' captions, but do you know a function that calculates the "length" of the caption of the tabpage (something like `length("Database tables") = 105`)?

Comment: I'm not sure what font is actually used by the ActiveX control but GET-TEXT-WIDTH-PIXELS method should give you a starting point.